# How to handle event, when user's camera becomes available or user don't have camera or microphone with WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, getusermedia

I use [SimpleWebRTC](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/SimpleWebRTC) library from Henrik Joreteg.
Where is in library such handler? Or where and how can I handle this (e.g. print message about this in console)

Comment: I thought that SimpleWebRTC took care of that and did its own error handling?

Comment: Yes. It is true. But I want to see, where this error handling in library.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/SimpleWebRTC/blob/master/simplewebrtc.bundle.js) at line 7030, you can see the error callback being used and trace it from there.

Comment: I did not get to bring a message to the console if the camera is not connected...

Comment: Sounds like a bug/new feature request should be made on the github site.

Comment: Line 7030 is still not correct, its 2016, can you be seriously, with responsibility answer this question kindly @BenjaminTrent?

Comment: @YumYumYum, I have never used that library before, that is why I just posted a comment in an effort to help give direction and not tried to give a full answer. Also, the that line is not correct because that the codebase has changed in the last 2 years. If you know better, then answer the question.